# concat 2 dataframes by multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Here I have two Nx1 dataframes(ds and code are indices, not columns). My purpose is, for each day, to concat open and close by code.

````
df1:

ds          code       open
20160101    001         1.4
            002         1.3
            003         1.2
```         ```         ```
20201231    001         12.3
            003         2.4
            007         3.4
````

and

````
df2:

ds          code       close
20160101    001         1.5
            002         1.12
            003         1.21
```         ```         ```
20201231    001         14.5
            003         2.2
            007         3.3
````

My ideal result is

````
ds          code       open       close
20160101    001         1.4         1.5
            002         1.3         1.12
            003         1.2         1.21
```         ```         ```
20201231    001         12.3        14.5
            003         2.4         2.2
            007         3.4         3.3
````

I tried to use the following method but it does not work

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 0)
```

No matter I add "keys" or "levels", I could not get the wanted result, any help would be appreciated

Comment: what is the output of `df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis = 1)`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `join` or `merge` to merge two dataframe.

```
df = df1.join(df2, how='outer')
```

if the index is not unique, `pd.concat` with `axis=1` will not work.